# Error During InstallShield Wizard

Tags: windows-installer

We are getting an error downloading a file for .NET 4.5 before our install. The error is an InstallShield Wizard error that says an error has occurred while downloading the file http://saturn.installshield.com/is/prerequisites/Microsoft.Net Framework 4.5 Web.prq.

The odd thing is, the error doesn’t make sense, it’s failing to download the prerequisite file.  This is a file that is inside the setup and tells it information about the prerequisite.  They shouldn’t even have to download that file.  So it’s not even .NET itself that’s failing to download.

Answer (score 0):

The PRQ on your build machine that you build against has an attribute called AltPRQ that optionally points to a web server.  The upside of this is it allows the PRQ to be tweaked long after a build has been produced. The downside is it injects a point of variability that can't be tracked using CM practices.  Personally I typically remove these references before doing a build.